# Forgot password in Firebase Authentication (better UI/UX)

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am developing a mobile app which uses Firebase Authentication.  When the user forgets his/her password, I am following these steps:

1- User is asked to enter his/her email.
2- User is forwarded to the attached screen (see image).
3- User receives an email with a link.
4- User clicks on the link in the email inside his device.

5- User is taking to another screen (in the mobile) to enter new password.

The problem I am faced with is that what if the user performs step # 4 but on his desktop.
Meaning that the user goes to his desktop and clicks on the link inside the email. In this case, the rest of the steps will resume from the desktop and the mobile app does not know if the user has changed his password. So the mobile app will remain at the attached screen.  What should I do to move the user to the sign in screen.

Obviously, I can add a third button which I can call "Continue" or "Resume" which when clicked will take the user to sign in.  But that has couple problems:

1- I will need to add a third button to the screen which is not super clean.

2- When the user clicks on the "Continue" or "Resume" button, there is no guarantee that the user has changed his/her password in the first place.  So there is no point of clicking the button in the first place.

One other solution would be to not allow the user to change password from the desktop by providing instructions to the user to go back to the mobile device and click on the link in the email over there.

Can some one suggest a nice way to handle this situation.

[image]

Comment: When you say "disk top" are you referring to a desktop?

Comment: Yes, I will fix the typo. Thanks

Comment: Most likely, should create a custom reset-password email handler. That you can always know when the password is changed.

Comment: How would you know if the password was changed?